# Ruby array of arrays and the map method

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary

I started with a CSV file, which I read into a CSV::Table, 104 columns, and wanted to filter it down to three:

```
filtered_data = csv.map { |row| row.fields(:x,:y:,:z) }
```

I then want to convert `x` from epoch time to regular GMT. I did this using:

```
filtered_data.each do |thing|
  thing[0] = Time.at(thing[0]).to_datetime
end
```

Thus yielding:

```
[[converted_x, y,z],[converted_x, y, z]]
```

Is there another way of doing this using the map function or is this the preferred solution?

---

Using Jeremy's answer I now have:

```
filtered_data.map { |x,y,z| [Time.at(x).to_datetime,y,z] }
```

And then further filtering using reject:

```
filtered_data.reject { |x,y,z| [x,y, z == '\\ '] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filtered_data.map do |x, y, z|
  [Time.at(x).to_datetime, y, z]
end
```